# Connecting metamask to custom networks returns `Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?`

Tags: metamask, rpc

I'm playing *Hack The Box blockchain challenges* and trying to connect to the custom network chain on Metamask. 
Network rpc URL: `http://142.93.32.153:32281/rpc` 
I recovered the chain id using the `cast command` from foundry framework:

```bash
brivan@0xbrivan:~$ cast chain-id -r http://142.93.32.153:32281/rpc
31337
```

When filling the necessary information, metamask says: Could not fetch chain ID, Is your RPC URL correct?
[image]

I'm sure the RPC URL is correct as I used to interact with it using foundry console commands.